# SetWindowsHookEx seems not working for me in C# (WH_KEYBOARD_LL, global)

Tags: c#, winapi, setwindowshookex

My application should perform some action whenever user pressed certain keys in windows.

Calling [`SetWindowsHookEx`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644990%28VS.85%29.aspx) with `WH_KEYBOARD_LL` option seems to be standard way to achieve this. However in my case something is clearly wrong and callback in not fired.

Main method of my debugging console application:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    IntPtr moduleHandle = GetCurrentModuleHandle();
    IntPtr hookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    try
    {
        User32.HookProc hook = (nCode, wParam, lParam) =>
        {
            // code is never called :-(
            if (nCode >= 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", wParam.ToInt32(), lParam.ToInt32());
            }
            return User32.CallNextHookEx(hookHandle, nCode, wParam, lParam);
        };

        hookHandle = User32.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook, moduleHandle, 0);

        Console.ReadLine(); // 
    }
    finally
    {
        if (hoodHandle != IntPtr.Zero)
        {
            var unhooked = User32.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hookHandle);
            Console.WriteLine(unhooked); // true
            hookHandle = IntPtr.Zero;                   
        }
    }
}
```

GetCurrentModuleHandle method:

```
private static IntPtr GetCurrentModuleHandle()
{
    using (var currentProcess = Process.GetCurrentProcess())
    using (var mainModule = currentProcess.MainModule)
    {
        var moduleName = mainModule.ModuleName;
        return Kernel32.GetModuleHandle(moduleName);
    }           
}
```

Imports from `user32.dll` and `kernel32.dll`:

```
public static class User32
{
    public const int WH_KEYBOARD_LL = 13;

    public delegate IntPtr HookProc(int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr SetWindowsHookEx(int idHook, HookProc lpfn, IntPtr hMod, uint dwThreadId);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool UnhookWindowsHookEx(IntPtr hhk);

    [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr CallNextHookEx(IntPtr hhk, int nCode, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);        
}

public static class Kernel32
{
    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetModuleHandle(string lpModuleName);
}
```

Do you have any idea what I is my problem?

Comment: Have you tried making your HookProc a real function, maybe there's something about the anonymous function declaration that's messing with it.  Just a shot in the dark...

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: I tried. Doesn't help :-(

Comment: Jakub, first thing I would do is get rid of anonymous method here.  Then, check for persistance of the class that contains that method - strange things occur when your managed delegate gets deleted and is still called from unmanaged code.

Comment: @Jakub: Is your GetModuleHandle() returning a valid module handle?  The MSDN documentation for `GetModuleHandle` indicates that if you pass in `NULL` for `lpModuleName` it will use the calling Process as it's default.  Maybe you can give this a shot and see if you get a better result. (More shooting in the dark =) )

Comment: Is this a console app? If so I think that would explain Cyril Gupta's answer.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: I tried. Doesn't help :-((

Comment: @Conrad Frix: Yes, it is. This may be problem. I'll try to do it in WinForms.

Comment: @Jakub: Ok, I'm out of bullets... sorry.

Comment: @Conrad Frix: You are right. The console application was the problem. Write it as answer please and I'll accept it.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla: Never mind. Thanks for trying.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this a console app as Main(string[] args) and Console.ReadLine() would suggest?

if so then this might be the source of your problem

Comment: Why would this be a problem?

Comment: @FrancoisBotha that's how it was  6 years ago. I believe now console apps can receive out of context windows notifications, but honestly I'm not up to date on WinAPI programming. If you're facing the same problem you should ask another question. If you have better information you might want to post an answer.

Comment: Ok, understood.

Answer (score 4):

The SetwindowHook API cannot be called from a C# console application. You need to call it in a Windows DLL (it won't work in a .Net DLL).

There is certainly a way to work around this issue, and I did use it one of the applications I built a long while ago. But I don't remember it right now. You may be able to find out if you search long enough.

Comment: Are you sure? It seems to work for others. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/setwindowshookex+c%23

Answer (score 2):

When you use the Win32 API like this, it is *very* important that you check for errors yourself.  You no longer have the friendly .NET wrappers that will do it for you and throw an exception.  This needs to be done in several places, but here's one:

```
    hookHandle = User32.SetWindowsHookEx(User32.WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hook, moduleHandle, 0);
    if (hookHandle == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
```

The real problem is your use of mainModule.ModuleName.  If only gives the name of the file, not the full path.  GetModuleHandle() will fail and return IntPtr.Zero.  As above, if you would have tested this then you'd have quickly found the problem.

There's an additional failure mode when you run this code in .NET 4.0.  The CLR no longer fakes native modules for managed code.  SetWindowsHookEx() needs a valid DLL handle but it doesn't actually use it since this is a low-level hook.  The best way to get one is to ask for user32.dll, it is always loaded in a managed program:

```
    IntPtr moduleHandle = LoadLibrary("user32.dll");
    if (moduleHandle == IntPtr.Zero) throw new Win32Exception();
```

No need to release it.

Comment: Thanks for answer. You are right I should always check return value of native calls. However this isn't issue. `UnhookWindowsHookEx` returns `true` so clearly callback was hooked.